# How to parse LocalDateTime to two digits millis in the end? Java

Tags: java, datetime, datetime-format

I want to parse LocalDateTime `2021-11-24T15:11:38.395` to LocalDateTime `2021-11-24T15:11:38.39`. But LocalDateTime.parse() always adds zero in the end, ignoring my pattern.

```
public class DateTimeFormatUtils {
    private static final String ISO_DATE_TIME = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SS";

    public static LocalDateTime formatToISO(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISO_DATE_TIME);
        return LocalDateTime.parse(formatter.format(localDateTime), formatter);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
        System.out.println(now);
        System.out.println(formatToISO(now));
    }

}
```

Output:

```
2021-11-30T11:48:28.449195200
2021-11-30T11:48:28.440
```

Is there way to deal with this problem?

Comment: What you are looking for is a specific _format_ of a local date time (i.e. a string), not a `LocalDateTime`. It's like asking "how do I get a `double` to represent `5`? I always get `5.0`"

Comment: Hm, ok, I got you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java Instant to LocalDateTime trailing zero](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314552/java-instant-to-localdatetime-trailing-zero). Also related: [Problem converting string to LocalDateTime \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70122794/problem-converting-string-to-localdatetime).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the strings "2021-11-24T15:11:38.39" and "2021-11-24T15:11:38.39**0**" represent the same `LocalDateTime`. Technically, you've already got your expected output!

Since you say that the output is not what you expect, you are actually expecting a `String` as the output, since "2021-11-24T15:11:38.39" and  "2021-11-24T15:11:38.390" are different *strings*. `formatToISO` should return a string - you should not parse the formatted date back to a `LocalDateTime`:

```
public static String formatToISO(final LocalDateTime localDateTime) {
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(ISO_DATE_TIME);
    return formatter.format(localDateTime);
}
```

This is similar to the common mistake of beginners printing out `double`s and expecting the specific format they have used to assign to the variable to come out.

```
double d = 5;
System.out.println(d); // expected 5, actual 5.0
```

`LocalDateTime`, just like `double`, doesn't store anything about how it should formatted. It just stores a *value*, and the same value will be formatted the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Java fraction-of-seconds is always return 3 digits.

Work around is, first convert LocalDateTime to String, then remove last character of the string.

Off course, please validate null checks.

```
private static String removeLastDigit(String localDateTime) {
        return localDateTime.substring(0, localDateTime.length()-1);
 }
```