# millisec not showing in localdatetime from long value conversion

Tags: java, datetime-format, long-integer, java-time, milliseconds

In our database, we have few long values like below

```
modified=1636334664000
created=1636334664000
```

if i use below code to convert, it doesnt show the format in millisec in it, it shows only up to seconds.
i have used below code

```
long modified = 1636334664000l;
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(
        Instant.ofEpochMilli(modified), ZoneId.systemDefault());
LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(ldt.toString());
dateTime = dateTime.atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)
        .toLocalDateTime();
Instant insStr = dateTime.toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

this gives me output as `"2021-11-08T01:24:24Z"` but i was expecting as `"2021-11-08T01:24:24.000Z"`.

used Java 8 date conversion as above.

Comment: An `Instant` cannot have a format. It cannot have or not have `.000` as fraction of second. Its `toString` method prints a fraction if it is non-zero and omits it if it is zero. Related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53314552/java-instant-to-localdatetime-trailing-zero) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58649073/array-of-instants-from-strings).

Comment: Also you are overcomplicating thingfs with your conversions. And also you haven’t got any good use for `LocalDateTime` (a much over-used class). To have `.000` printed you need to format your datetime value into a string. `Instant` cannot be formatted, so convert to an `OffsetDateTime` in UTC and format it: `Instant .ofEpochMilli(1_636_334_664_000L) .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))`. Result: `2021-11-08T01:24:24.000Z`.

Comment: And a detail I find worth considering: use upper case `L` to mark o `long`. It is so easy to confuse lower case `l` with digit `1`.

Comment: Also I cannot reproduce. I get a compile error from your code: *'parse(java.lang.CharSequence)' in 'java.time.LocalDateTime' cannot be applied to '(java.time.LocalDateTime)'*

Comment: `1636334664000l` has one too many digits. Presumably you meant `163633466400l`.

Comment: By “expecting as "2021-11-08T01:24:24.000Z".” did you mean “expecting as "2021-11-08T01:24:24.001Z".” with a millisecond in the fraction?

Comment: Please take more care when posting on Stack Overflow. Such careless typos in important example data is confusing, and may waste the time of those whose help you are requesting.

Comment: @BasilBourque You are confirming what i said. :-) `1636334664000l` has not got too many digits. It’s confusingly got a trailing lower case letter l (without which Java would not accept it as a literal). It does correspond to what the OP says, 2021-11-08T01:24:24Z (with zero fraction of second).

Comment: thanks @OleV.V. your given solution is working now if input is long but if the input is instance of LocalDateTime, how can i acheive similar output format with .000Z ?

Comment: Thanks @BasilBourque i have fixed compile issues, can u suggest how can i achieve .000Z if the input is localDateTime object instead of long as for long we got the solution above.

Comment: `ldt .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()) .withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC) .format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSX"))`. This converts to UTC and formats using the same formatter as above, that is, with `.000Z` if the fraction of second is zero. I recommend you extract the formatter into a constant.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

After  **correcting multiple typos** in the example data of your Question, we find no errors, no surprises, when running the code. Your millisecond appears as expected.

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_636_334_664_001L ).toString()
```

> 2021-11-08T01:24:24.001Z

## `LocalDateTime` not helpful in your case

`LocalDateTime` is the wrong class to use here. That class represents a date with time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset-from-UTC. So that class cannot represent a moment, a specific point on the timeline.

To track moments use:

- `Instant`
- `OffsetDateTime`
- `ZonedDateTime`

## Use `Instant`

Assuming your long values represent a count of milliseconds since the epoch reference of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z, use `Instant.ofEpochMilli`.

Your `1636334664000l` example presumably has a typo, one too many zero digits. I will go with `163633466400l`.

When hard-coding such `long` values, use the optional underscore (`_`) digit grouping feature in Java. And  append an `L` to ensure parsing as a `long` primitive.

```java
Instant created = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_636_334_664_000L ) ;
Instant modified = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_636_334_664_001L ) ;
```

Calculate elapsed time.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( created , modified ) ;
```

We expect to see a single millisecond as our result. The result is presented in standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) format.

Dump to console.

```java
System.out.println( created ) ;
System.out.println( modified ) ;
System.out.println( duration ) ;
```

[Execute at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/x4jCW1). We see your expected fractional second, a [millisecond](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Millisecond).

```
2021-11-08T01:24:24Z
2021-11-08T01:24:24.001Z
PT0.001S
```

## `ZonedDateTime`

See that same moment through the wall-clock time of a particular time zone.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Asia/Tokyo" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtModifiedTokyo = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

We continue to see your fractional second, a single millisecond.

> zdtModifiedTokyo.toString(): 2021-11-08T10:24:24.001+09:00[Asia/Tokyo]

Comment: There’s a wealth of good information here, thanks. I think the OP meant to ask, though, why are they not getting the expected output of `2021-11-08T01:24:24.000Z` with a printed decimal fraction of `.000` (three zeroes)?